# Field clashes in django orm

Tags: python, django

I have some problems with Django ORM.
I have three classes:

transaction.py

```py
class Transaction(models.Model):

    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        PENDING = 'Pending'
        PROCESSING = 'Processing'
        CHARGED = 'Charged'
        AUTHORIZED = 'Authorized'
        CANCELLED = 'Cancelled'
        REJECTED = 'Rejected'
        ERROR = 'Error'
        ISSUED = 'Issued'

    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)  # in USD
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        choices=Status.choices,
        default=Status.PROCESSING,
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    from_account = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    to_account = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

payments.py

```
class Payment(Transaction):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Payment {super().__str__()}"


class Refund(Payment):
    payment = models.ForeignKey(
        Payment,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='parent_payment'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Refund payment={self.payment.id} {super(Transaction, self).__str__()}"
```

And when I trying to do migration I have this error

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
booking.Refund.payment: (models.E006) The field 'payment' clashes with the field 'payment' from model 'booking.transaction'.
```

As I understand the problem related to inheritance and its specific in ORM, but I'm not sure

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to subclass Refund from Payment or from Transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add it

```
class Meta:
abstract = True
```

Comment: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. Please make sure your code is free of syntax errors when submitting answers.